# Html content comes on top of navbar

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a problem my html content comes on top of my navbar even tho I'm including it in my {%block content%}
This is my base template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@2.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/styles.css" %}'>
</head>

<body>
{% include 'navbar.html'%}

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my navbar

```
<div>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo"> <i class="ri-home-2-fill"></i><span>LOGO</span></a>
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Soon</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="main">
            <a href="#" class="user"><i class="ri-nurse-fill"></i>Sign in</a>
            <a href="#">Register</a>
            <div class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
    </div>
```

And this is a page of my app

```
{% extends 'main.html'%}
{% block content %}
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's my css file as well

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

:root {
    --bg-color: #B8E2FE;
    --text-color: #fff;
    --main-color: #008BB0;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--text-color)
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 28px 12%;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo i {
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.logo span {
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
}

.navbar a {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0px 30px;
    transition: all 0.50s ease;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.navbar a.active {
    color: var(--main-color)
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.main a {
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: all 0.50s ease;
}

.user {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.user i {
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-right: 7px;

}

.main a:hover {
    color: var(--main-color);
}

#menu-icon {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10001;
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
    header {
        padding: 14px 2%;
        transition: .2s;
    }

    .navbar a {
        padding: 5px 0;
        margin: 0px 20px;

    }
}

@media (max-width: 1090px) {
    #menu-icon {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        right: -100%;
        width: 270px;
        height: 29vh;
        background-color: var(--main-color);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: all 0.50s ease;
    }

    .navbar a {
        display: block;
        margin: 12px 0;
        padding: 0px 25px;
        transition: all 0.50s ease;
    }

    .navbar a:hover {
        color: var(--text-color);
        transform: translateY(5px);
    }

    .navbar a.active {
        color: var(--text-color);
    }

    .navbar.open {
        right: 2%;

    }
}
```

Here's what I got, would really appreciate help since I can't seem to find where's the problem
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ehKg.png)

Comment: what happens if you add line breaks `<br>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: fixed` makes the header fixed to the viewport and takes it out of the document flow (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for details). Thus the content below it will render as though it wasn't there. A quick fix is just to replace `position: fixed;` to `position: sticky;` but the header will scroll with the content. A better solution would be to add: `position: sticky` to the parent div as per the marked up code below. When scrolling the content will appear beneath but you can fix this by giving your header a background colour.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

:root {
    --bg-color: #B8E2FE;
    --text-color: #fff;
    --main-color: #008BB0;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--text-color)
}

/* added this */
.header-container {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

header {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*top: 0; */
    /* right: 0; */
    /* z-index: 1000; */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*background: transparent;*/
    background-color: lightskyblue; /* added this */
    padding: 28px 12%;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@2.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/styles.css" %}'>
</head>

<body>
<div class='header-container'><!-- added this -->
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo"> <i class="ri-home-2-fill"></i><span>LOGO</span></a>
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Soon</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="main">
            <a href="#" class="user"><i class="ri-nurse-fill"></i>Sign in</a>
            <a href="#">Register</a>
            <div class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
    </div>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p><p>line</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```